# Tags inside textarea

Tags: html, textarea

I have an administrative area with some elements (2 fields text and ID and sort field) and each elements can be manage by create/edit/delete actions

And I think that I can make it easier by using textarea, where administrator can operates items as a text

```
<textarea>
  <item1:1>
  <item2:3>
</textarea>
```

where each item is included into < and > and it have the identifier after colon, so administrator can easily sort elements and rename them.

I just tested it one user and he said that numbers are confuse him.

May be put the numbers with colon into span tag and make it in different color....

what do you think? does textarea allowed tags? Is it more simple than working with items?

Answer (score 10):

The content model for textarea is #PCDATA (processed character data). This means elements inside will not be accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Anyone who comes across this might want to use a "content editable div" e.g.

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/XNkDx/

thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705882/194309