# Rendering HTML inside textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I need to be able to render some HTML tags inside a textarea (namely <strong>, <i>, <u>, <a>) but textareas only interpret their content as text. Is there an easy way of doing it without relying on external libraries/plugins (I'm using jQuery)?
If not, do you know of any jQuery plugin I could use to do this?

Comment: The only way to do that will be to overlay your HTML markup over the content of the textarea tag via CSS positioning tricks. Nothing will help you convince the browser to render the textarea contents differently. (Why exactly do you "need" to do this?)

Comment: I just need the user to be able to add some formatting styles to the text he enters (much like when you write an article on Wordpress). I just do not need all the features like text alignment and so on, but only those basic tags.

Comment: For bold and italic you could hack the Unicode characters together, for example: , , , . In other words, you need a function that replaces them on input. There should also be underline and strikethrough Unicode characters.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

This is not possible to do with a `textarea`. You are looking for a [content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) div, which is very easily done:

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/8zevmL4d/)

```css
div.editable {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
}

strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">This is the first line.<br>
See, how the text fits here, also if<br>there is a <strong>linebreak</strong> at the end?
<br>It works nicely.
<br>
<br><span style="color: lightgreen">Great</span>.
</div>
```

Comment: its a real shame that you can't practically use this without the use of javascript to either submit your changes using ajax or copy them into a form input. If anyone has found a way to do it i'd be really interested!

Comment: @yckart: Well, I don't think that's actually valid, even though it works in all browsers I've tried. [`contenteditable` is an enumerated attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) rather than a Boolean attribute (there's an `inherit` state as well as `true` and `false`) , and I *think* that means that specifying a value is mandatory, although I can't find a definitive bit of the spec to confirm this. MDN [seems to agree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#contenteditable) though.

Comment: @yckart: I'm not 100% sure though. The fact that `<div contenteditable></div>` works in all browsers does make me wonder :)

Comment: @TimDown I've fiddled a bit around and it seems that `contenteditable` **without** `true` or `false` doesn't inherit from its parent, as [MDN *says*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#contenteditable): http://jsbin.com/eqelip/1/edit

Comment: @yckart: I'd assumed the browser interprets `contenteditable` with no value as being the same as `contenteditable=""`, which in turn is the same as `contenteditable="true"`.

Comment: @TimDown That's exactly how it's interpreted. However, I think it's a rather bad practice to omit the value, even though it works.

Comment: This doesn't work any better than a `textarea`. Typing `<strong>someting</strong>` into the fiddle leaves you with that exact text. The HTML is not applied.

Comment: @MattEllen `contenteditable` turns the element into a rich text editor, so you can use `ctrl+b` and `ctrl+i` to make text bold or italic. It does not parse HTML though, that you'll have to deal with yourself, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XNkDx/2917/).

Comment: @MarcusEkwall but wasn't the question asking for html rendering?

Comment: can a placeholder be added inside this ?

Comment: @NDZIEPatrickJoel Please refrain from linking to w3schools. They're a business that makes money off of phony certificates. Also, they don't allow anyone to contribute or fix bad code.

Use MDN instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable

Comment: @mekwall. Despite whatever errors may be in w3schools, what they have over all the theoretical sites is that you can easily experiment in there, using multiple browsers, to see what actually happens! MDN is good for the completeness of coverage.

Comment: As opposed to using editablecontent, I just used [innerHTML] within my div to accomplish what I needed:              <div [innerHTML]="selectedLevel.longDescription"></div>

Comment: That's why you need to think twice before starting your words with 'This is not possible'

Comment: @0014 What do you mean?

Comment: @mekwall please see the solution merlin has provided. It is very well possible to render HTML in a textarea. Even though you have provided a good solution, you started your words with 'This is not possible' which generally speaking tends to be not true.

Comment: @0014 You did notice the answer was written in 2011, right? AFAIK it wasn't possible back then. Feel free to contribute to it if you want.

Answer (score 40):

With an editable div you can use the method `document.execCommand` ([more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand)) to easily provide the support for the tags you specified and for some other functionality...

```css
#text {
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="text" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button onclick="document.execCommand('bold');">toggle bold</button>
<button onclick="document.execCommand('italic');">toggle italic</button>
<button onclick="document.execCommand('underline');">toggle underline</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in some browsers just adding this as a note AS of '16

Comment: [96% usage as of 2020](https://caniuse.com/?search=document.execCommand)

Comment: this is WOW - just WOW -saving me tons of work!

Comment: looks like it is deprecated - what a shame

Answer (score 10):

Since you only said render, yes you can. You could do something along the lines of this:

```js
function render(){
 var inp     = document.getElementById("box");
 var data = `
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="${inp.offsetWidth}" height="${inp.offsetHeight}">
<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
style="font-family:monospace;font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-size:13.3px;padding:2px;;">
${inp.value} <i style="color:red">cant touch this</i>
</div>
</foreignObject>
</svg>`;
 var blob = new Blob( [data], {type:'image/svg+xml'} );
 var url=URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 inp.style.backgroundImage="url("+URL.createObjectURL(blob)+")";
 }
 onload=function(){
  render();
  ro = new ResizeObserver(render);
 ro.observe(document.getElementById("box"));
 }
```

```css
#box{
  color:transparent;
  caret-color: black;
  font-style: normal;/*must be same as in the svg for caret to align*/
  font-variant: normal; 
  font-size:13.3px;
  padding:2px;
  font-family:monospace;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="box" oninput="render()">you can edit me!</textarea>
```

This makes it so that a `textarea` will render html!
Besides the flashing when resizing, inability to directly use classes and having to make sure that the div in the `svg` has the same format as the `textarea` for the caret to align correctly, it's works!

Comment: Interesting approach! Never thought of SVG graphics coming in handy here. But breaks when you add a `<` into the text.

Comment: @Avatar though I didn't show it in this example for simplicities sake, you could work on a custom text parser to work with this. This added with a drawn text cursor rather than the default web cursor would enable you to do custom text much more easily. For example you can currently paste `<b>hello</b>` to get bold text.
Adding a custom text parser to it and the possibilities are endless. You could make every `a` character red for example. I can see if I can find a more flushed out version of this I made a while ago If you would like.

Comment: @Avatar I managed to find it though I have no idea what it even does anymore (I think it makes Ascii art by drawing lines above characters).
https://jsbin.com/lacobib/3/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is advanced, maybe I will try an implementation in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Try this example:

```js
function toggleRed() {
  var text = $('.editable').text();
  $('.editable').html('<p style="color:red">' + text + '</p>');
}

function toggleItalic() {
  var text = $('.editable').text();
  $('.editable').html("<i>" + text + "</i>");
}

$('.bold').click(function() {
  toggleRed();
});

$('.italic').click(function() {
  toggleItalic();
});
```

```css
.editable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button class="bold">toggle red</button>
<button class="italic">toggle italic</button>
```

Comment: what about applying style to only part of text?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What is the gist of it?

Answer (score 3):

An addendum to this: You can use character entities (such as changing `<div>` to `&lt;div&gt;`) and it will render in the textarea.

But when it is saved, the value of the textarea is the text *as rendered*. So you don't need to de-encode. I just tested this across browsers (Internet Explorer back to [version 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_11)).

Comment: I would really like for this to work for me but it didn't. For example `<textarea>
            check for url &lt;B&gt;http://localhost/Dashboard.aspx&lt;/B&gt;
&lt;BR&gt;
Tool Started at &lt;B&gt;11/10/2015 3:56:58 AM&lt;/B&gt;
&lt;BR&gt; .... </textarea>` does not display as HTML. I'm on Chrome 46.

Comment: Hm. I copy-pasted that string directly into an html document and it renders the markup properly for me in Chrome Version 48.0.2552.0 dev (64-bit) OS X 10.11.1. So maybe it's a version problem.

Comment: I keep getting down-voted for this so here's a pen: http://codepen.io/axlotl/pen/YGZOEq

Comment: if you put &lt;i&gt; test &lt;i&gt; then will it be shown in italic? no! but that is what is meant by "render".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but in reverse, and the following solution. I want to put html from a div in a textarea (so I can edit some reactions on my website; I want to have the textarea in the same location.)

To put the content of this div in a textarea I use:

```js
var content = $('#msg500').text();
$('#msg500').wrapInner('<textarea>' + content + '</textarea>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="msg500">here some <strong>html</strong> <i>tags</i>.</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

This is possible with `<textarea>`.
You only need to use the [Summernote WYSIWYG editor](http://summernote.org/getting-started/#installation).

It interprets HTML tags inside a textarea (namely `<strong>`, `<i>`, `<u>`, and `<a>`).

Comment: It does not use textarea. It uses div, which cannot be submitted with a form.

Comment: It does work with textarea, just try giving id to textarea instead of div.
I created a whole project using textarea and  summernote. It works fine!

Comment: Whats the point? It behaves same as ckeditor if textarea is used. Can't render HTML tags as asked.

Comment: Why should I use a WYSIWYG editor? This is really not an answer, sorry.

Comment: It doesn't use textarea. Not an answer.