# display div inside text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to display html in a text area. Is it possible to display a `<div>` containing form elements inside a `<textarea>` using javascript or jquery?

Comment: You can put only html content inside of `textarea` but you cant display it like an element inside of container.

Comment: You could take a look at some of the existing open source WYSIWYG editors. Unless your project is to build a WYSIWYG I highly recommend using those, since it is a lot of work to perfect and maintain a WYSIWYG. It's often made up of hacks, so cross-browser optimization is a b**ch. Personally I use www.ckeditor.com.

Comment: If you had to do something like this you would be looking at making the textarea background transparent and absolutely positioning the content you want behind the textarea.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this, what is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot place HTML elements inside a text area, only text content.

Comment: @Juicy Scripter Nice counter :-)

Comment: `only text content` covers that part.

Comment: PARTIALLY true, you can with javascript/jquery. See @Abdul Jabbar Dumrai below. Simply, it will not be interpreted as html, but it can still be useful as hidden textarea for forms

Comment: What is partially true about my answer? The question was putting HTML inside a `<textarea>` element and have it rendered like HTML. Abdul's answer is putting  html in a `<div>` and making it editable. The question lacks clarification on what they were trying to ultimately accomplish only whether what they asked is possible, which it is not.

Answer (score 25):

You cannot put div in textarea but sometimes you need to do so. Good news is that you can do it in other way by using **contenteditable** property of elements. Like

```
 <div contenteditable="true" style="min-height:50px; width:300px;" id="txtDiv">
 </div>
```

This Div will behave exactly like a Textarea but you can append anything you want. And remember when you want to grab data from inside it in jquery

```
 var ContentofDiv = $('#txtDiv').html();
```

Now you can append childs just like others.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using div with contenteditable attribute, instead of a textarea, like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <div>inner div</div>
</div>
```

But if you try to change the innerhtml of this div dynamically then remember, you'll have to manage caret location by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible(it will not render the UI). If you want to show form fields why are you using `textarea`? You can just use normal html.

Answer (score 0):

As such, it's not possible to use html tags in a `<textarea>`. You have to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question when I was looking for a solution for something entirely else but however... With a wrapper you can easily place your input over your textarea. I'm not sure how much sense that makes but I believe it answers your question anyway.

```css
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
}

.wrapper textarea {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  resize: none;
  z-index:1;
}

.wrapper input[name="test2"] {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50px;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea name="test1">This is</textarea>
  <input type="text" name="test2" placeholder="(Sparta?)">
</div>
```