# Sending a square root sign to a textarea

Tags: javascript, php

When the user click on a button mark with the square root sign,
it sends the square root sign inside a textarea. Is there a way to do this with php.
If not javascript is fine?

Comment: No need for PHP, Javascript will do it just fine.

Comment: if you want php to do it, you'd either have to do a full-blown server round trip with form submission, or output it when the page is generated.

Comment: Javascript runs on the _client_ (browser) -- PHP runs on the _server_ -- so to get PHP to do it you would need a round trip to the server. (aaaaannd - Mark B posted while I typed this)

Comment: I forgot to say that I don't know how to do it and I am looking for a a code. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`ell=document.getElementById('your_textarea's_id');

ell.innerHTML = ell.innerHTML + "&#8730;";`

**Explanantion:**
`&#8730;` is the html encoding of the square root symbol. This bit of javascript takes adds the √ symbol to whatever was already in the text area (not sure, but my guess is you're writing a calculator of sorts). This version preserves what was in the textarea before instead of writing over it which is important in most cases.

You can use [This table](http://www.dionysia.org/html/entities/symbols.html) of symbols to entities to use the same code for any math operator you want.

Answer (score 1):

Not that straight forward. 
Use `.value` and you get the entity `&#8730;` or `&radic;` instead of √ unless you set the value to something that already rendered the character

this works in Chrome:

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/QxTCW/)

```
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById("but").onclick=function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value+=this.innerHTML;
      return false;
    }
}
```

using

```
<button id="but">&#8730;</button>
<textarea></textarea>
```

The direct innerHTML version is this

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].innerHTML+="&#8730;"
```

Comment: If I can do it for at least 2 math symbols, I could manage to do it for more. How can I improve the code to add a division sign please do?

Comment: It works when the form is only html. However, it does not work when the action attribute of the form is a php page. When clicked, the php page set in the action attribute is loaded instead of sending the square root sign inside the textarea. Please help!

Comment: Add a return false to the function

Comment: The code works. I have an accordion with multiple textarea. The square root sign dispays only in the first one. However, when I change

Comment: The code works. Thank you. However, I have an accordion with multiple textarea. The square root sign dispays only in the first one. However, when I change ("textarea")[0] to ("textarea")[1] it shows up in the next textarea at the bottom. However, the button that I have at  ("textarea")[1] does not work. I have to hit the button from ("textarea")[0] for the square root sign to display in ("textarea")[1]. How do I fix this? I feel that I am close. Please help me finish this.

Comment: I have no idea since you did not post any html. [0] is the first textarea on the page. Change to `document.getElementById("IDOfYourTextarea").value` for each of the areas after giving them a unique ID

Answer (score 0):

This might be relevant:
[Displaying MathML symbols inside a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590359/displaying-mathml-symbols-inside-a-textarea)

By the way, the character entity is `&radic;`

Comment: &#8730; is also correct. HTML has encodings for most characters in all the standard bases.

Comment: You are absolutely right, Yitzchak. I only meant that `&radic;` is easier to read. :)