# How do I enable HTML for a Textarea?

Tags: html, textarea

How do I enable HTML for textareas? Do I need to get some kind of text editor or can I just enable it? I need help with this. I'm making user-written game walkthroughs and they want HTML enabled so they can add images, videos, etc.

So, how do I?

Comment: Please explain *enable HTML for textareas*. There are no out-of-the-box restictions to what you can send to a server via a `<textarea>`-element.

Comment: refer this first  [Rendering HTML inside textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. When typing into a `textarea`, the information being entered is literally just strings of characters. I could type the following:

`<h1>Hello, World!</h1> Here is some text <br/> Here is some more <ul><li>This is a list</li></ul>`

But the browser treats it as simply a sequence of characters, no more than if you were to just type this:

`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`.

If you're trying to get hand-written HTML parsed and displayed as *code*, then you need to use some Javascript that reads the contents of the text and puts it into an empty `div` or some other element that is meant to be filled with `code` instead of `text`.

An example with jQuery:

```
<textarea id="inputBox">
    type some HTML inside me
</textarea>
<div id="resultsBox"></div>

<script>
$('#inputBox').on('input',function() {
    $('#resultsBox').html($('#inputBox').val());
});
</script>
```

This code listens for when the user types something into the `textarea` and inserts that data *as HTML* into the `div`.

The point is that you can't have text in a textarea 'turn into' HTML without somewhow loading it into a non-text-input element. Until you do that, the entered data is simply a string.

*Note that even invalid and unfinished HTML will be inserted in this example.*