# How to render HTML template in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, templates

I have a textarea and a resume/CV sample template on document.

On button event that template's HTML is the value of textarea.

I am doing it as below-

```
$(function(){
    $('#select-sample').click(function(){
    var sample=$('.ok').html();
        $('.summernote').val(sample);
    });

});
```

This is just a simple copy thing is happening in textarea, I am picking up an HTML of template and copying it into textarea.

**My question-**

How do I render that HTML template in textarea as it is rendered in document. I don't want rendered HTML.

Why won't Textarea render this HTML template when all related css classes are attached within document itself?

[Fiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/qyyap/1/)

Comment: try this: $('.summernote').text(sample) or html(sample)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering HTML inside textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Comment: Is there a way to potentially get the text (with html) inside of a textarea? Because whenever I do, and try putting the value in a <div>, the tags don't show anything. It shows the tags still???

Answer (score 3):

Textarea elements are intended only for text input or manipulation, they have nothing to do with rendering. If you want to render, make a div: `<div class="summernote"></div>`. 
And change your jQuery to: `$('.summernote').html(sample);`

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `textarea` element only shows text, if you wish to use markup you will need to make use of javascript and the `contenteditable` property or include a `wysiwyg` editor script, many of those can be easily found, although one of the most well known editors would be `tinyMCE`.

Comment: In real scenario , I am using summernote texteditor for this job. But this editor doesn't seem to take values in it.

Comment: @Manoz then you should have mentioned that you are using an editor, and you should look into the editors own API on how to input content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('.summernote').code(sHTML);`

http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/features.html#api-code