# Apply a:before not for images

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I recently finished a website in `wordpress` and modified a template a bit.
Now my customer wants a element before a `text-links`, so i tried adding a :before as shown

```
a:before {
    content:url('triangle.png');
    width:3px;
    height:5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

what it does, works great so far:

[image]

But my problem is that I have image links on my site as well, and it crashes my layout.

Is it possible to apply the `a:before` only for the links in the `textarea` ?

Comment: You have anchor tags in textarea? never did that before. Anyway, try `textarea a:before` instead of `a:before` in css.

Comment: check thoroughly every webpage because you are not using specific class name for styling. There is 90% chance that the styling is also being applied to other anchor elements too.

Comment: yeppp... still got problems here :/

http://puu.sh/7Mzgt.jpg

Comment: post the exact related html where you want to apply this stylings. we might able to help you :) (_ofcourse hide private content_)

Comment: `textarea` contain raw data only. @Mr_Green `textarea a:before` this will not work

Comment: @RahilWazir yeah I was confused with OP's statement: "_Is it possible to apply the a:before only for the links in the **textarea** ?_"

Comment: I guess you are not really talking about the html element <textarea>? If yes, you should probably read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea

Comment: can u post more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried following:

```
a:before > img {
    content:"";
    width:3px; /*maybe these styles are also not necessary for your layout*/
    height:5px; /* then you can set them al to 0 */
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Might want the child-specific selector `a:before > img {` rather than the (any-)descendent selector `a:before img {`

Comment: @Stephen P: thanks for the remark! I'll change my answer accordingly.