# html_safe not working on the input fields text in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database, html-safe

I have tried to display text in input field like `text_area` but here text data is not plain text and it has some html tags also.

Ex:-

```
'<%= f.text_area :email_message, :value => "#{@message}".html_safe %>'
```

I have used `html_safe` for this text to avoid tags and get html formatting effect but no success.

Hope we need to use text editor for this kind of text display.

Is there any idea to achieve it without text editor in rails..?

Please share your comments/ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post what inside `@message` variable.

Comment: Its data from db like "I want to display text in <b> bold</b>."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering HTML inside textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Comment: Use Like '<%= f.text_area :email_message, :value => ' + #{@message} + '.html_safe %>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put html in a text area.