# php does not work correctly with textarea tag and displays the rest of the html tags when i use textarea

Tags: php, html, css

So I have this code:

```
<?php
    echo "<textarea style='width:500px; height:600px'>";

    while($extract = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        echo "<span class='usr'>" . $extract['usr'] . "</span>: <span class='msg'>" . $extract['msg'] . "</span><br/>";
    }

    echo "</textarea>";

    $result->close();
    $conexion->close();
?>
```

And the output in the text area gives me this:

`<span class='usr'>dsdsds</span>: <span class='msg'>aaaaa</span><br/>`

Answer (score 2):

You can't use HTML code inside a `<textarea>` to render HTML.

[Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Comment: is there another way to do it?? It works fine without the textarea tag.