# how to set css and html in textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

Is it possible to set a mark (html) in textarea? Because (I think thats for everyone clear) if you set:
`<textarea><mark>this text has a mark</mark></textarea>` that this not works

Is it just possible to give an element in a textarea an exact color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well your question, you want to know if it is possible to include HTML content into a TEXTAREA element.

That is not possible, but you can look at the solution proposed by the following post, which consists in using an editable DIV element: [Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

only add this

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Your description..."></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks but im not looking for placeholder, i try to change the color of a few words in a textarea