# How to use multiple font face in single text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-face

How to use multiple font face in single textarea?

Example:

```
<style>
@font-face {    
     font-family: 'MULLAI';     
     src: url('MULLAI.woff') format('woff'); 
           }  
.tamil { 
     font-family:MULLAI; 
     font-size:18px; 
      }
.english { 
    font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
    font-size:13px; 
         } 
</style>
```

`<textarea><a class="english">Hello</a>,<a class="tamil">ïH¥Õ£L</a></textarea>`

I am expecting the output should be

> Hello வணக்கம்

Actually i need to include multiple languages in single text area. I tried lots of jquery editor. But its not supporting multiple languages in single textarea.
Please help me to resolve this problem.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: instead use `content editable` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot** do it. DOM cannot be insert to `textarea` element. You can use `content editable` for it. Also you can find more information [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)