# html tags within text-area tag Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to add `P`, `H(n)[1-6]` tags in textarea tag.

```html
<center>
  <h4>P tag in textaera tag</h4>
  <textarea>
    P tag below : 
    <p>This is a sentence.</p>
  </textarea>
</center>
```

Comment: No you can't add a tag inside `<textarea>` tag

Comment: You can use [`contenteditable`](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to do it into a textarea, but you can do it within an editable div like below :

```html
<div contenteditable="true"><b>Blabla</b> <i>its working</i></div>
```

Source :

[Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Comment: why div instead of text-area?

Comment: You can't direclty render html's tag into a textarea, but you can achieve something similar by creating a editable <div>