# Bold String in TextArea using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am auto populating text in a text area based on a value selected from a ddl.

Now I can get the text to appear, but I would like that text to be **bold**.

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#activityID').change(function () {
    var selectedActivity = this.options[this.selectedIndex].parentNode.label;
    var text = "Event Name: \nEvent Location: \nEstimated # of Participants:"
    var result = text.bold();
    if (selectedActivity === "DEMONSTRATIONS") {
        $('#Summary').val(result);
    }
    else if (selectedActivity !== "DEMONSTRATIONS") {
        $('#Summary').val("");
    }
});
});
```

In the *TextArea* it is rendering as:

```
<B>Event Name: 
Event Location: 
Estimated # of Participants:</B>
```

Is there any possible way to get this text to render as bold when that specific item is chosen from the DDL?

I have referenced [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_str_bold) but this did the same thing as above.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to format all text in the text area? Or selectively format it?

Comment: A basic textarea does not support selective formatting. You would need a plugin to make it support rich text.

Comment: NOTE: `string.bold()` is deprecated and shouldn't be used.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold

Comment: @jwatts1980 I only want the string that is in the `var text` to be in bold.. but whatever the text that the user enters in after that to be normal.. no bold

Comment: In that case you will need some sort of plugin

Comment: related [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Comment: Of relevance to the link posted by @Gunther34567 : http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable

Comment: @Gunther34567 that did work. thank you. now just need to find a way so that only the text that is auto populated to be bold and not what the user types in

Comment: @jwatts1980 that did work. thank you. now just need to find a way so that only the text that is auto populated to be bold and not what the user types in

Comment: @jwatts1980 do you know of any plugins off the top of your head that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What he said above, but quote the word bold:

```
var result = $("<span>").text(text).css({ 'font-weight': 'bold' });
```

Or better yet, apply a CSS class to the field and associate that class with bold in your css files.

```
var result = $("<span>").text(text).addClass('mybold');
```

And in your css:

```
span.mybold: { font-weight: bold; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text to appear bold, you should be changing the CSS properties of the element.

```
var result = $("<span>").text(text).css({ 'font-weight': 'bold' });
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Edited my answer. Bold should be a string.