# Insert HTML tag for selected text inside paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am trying to add new element for selected element in paragraph tag.
HTML code snippet as below:

```
 <div class="parent-bodytext">
     <p>Hello</p>
     <p>This one is</p>
     <p>Sample Text</p>
 </div>
```

So in above snippet I have selected "one" word from second P tag and using any event I am trying to add element to that selected text so that output will be like below:

```
 <div class="parent-bodytext">
     <p>Hello</p>
     <p>This <strong>one</strong> is</p>
     <p>Sample Text</p>
 </div>
```

So How can add this newly created "Strong" element for selected the selected text?

Comment: Please explain more when you need to add strong tag

Comment: @Justcode if I select any button, so that strong tag should get added to that selected text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make selected text bold/italic/underlined in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38218268/how-to-make-selected-text-bold-italic-underlined-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but i thing this is not possible to append strong tag with selected text if you want to do this you need to use some text editor like ckeditor https://ckeditor.com/ and use css to hide the border etc so it will show like the original page.

Comment: @YaseenAhmad I am trying this part in CKEditor only. Do you aware how to achieve this with CKEditor?

Comment: @AvinashJadhav see this link http://jsfiddle.net/pq8yg5ke/ let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @YaseenAhmad that's exactly what I am looking. Can you please elaborate the javascript code ? I did not find anything there.

Comment: I answer the question all code available hop it will help you. best of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use [window.getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) for this purpose

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('parent-bodytext')[0];

wrapper.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
   const selection = window.getSelection();
   if (selection.rangeCount) {
       const replacement = document.createElement('strong');
       replacement.textContent = selection.toString();
       const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
       range.deleteContents();
       range.insertNode(replacement);
   }
});
```

```html
 <div class="parent-bodytext">
 <p>Hello</p>
 <p>This one is</p>
 <p>Sample Text</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you want something like this?

```js
window.onload = () => {
  function getSelectionParentElement() {
    var parentEl = null,
      sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
      sel = window.getSelection();
      if (sel.rangeCount) {
        parentEl = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
        if (parentEl.nodeType != 1) {
          parentEl = parentEl.parentNode;
        }
      }
    } else if ((sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
      parentEl = sel.createRange().parentElement();
    }
    return parentEl;
  }

  function getSelectedText() {
    var text = "";
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
      text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (
      typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
      document.selection.type == "Text"
    ) {
      text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
  }
  
  const makeBold = (selectStart, selectEnd, length, text)=>{
    let replacedText = `<strong>${text.substr(selectStart, length)}</strong>`;
    let textHalfA = text.substr(0, selectStart);
    let textHalfB = text.substr(selectEnd, text.length - 1);
    return textHalfA + replacedText + textHalfB;
  };
  
  function handleMouseUp() {
    // the selected text
    const text = getSelectedText();
    // the length of the selected content
    const selectedTextLength = text.length;
    // the parent of the selected content
    let parent = getSelectionParentElement();
    // the entire content of the parent
    let parentText = parent.innerHTML;
    // where the user's selection starts
    let selectStart = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
    // where the user's selection ends
    let selectEnd = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset;
    if (parent) {
      parent.innerHTML = makeBold(selectStart, selectEnd, selectedTextLength, parentText);
    }
  }

  document.onmouseup = handleMouseUp;
  document.onkeyup = handleMouseUp;
};
```

```html
<p>I am a sentence.</p>
```

Sources would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712310/javascript-how-to-detect-if-a-word-is-highlighted) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215479/get-parent-element-of-a-selected-text).

Also, here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/ebjeZr) :)

---

Edit: Code's updated. The modification of the selected content should be done correctly now. Although, I have no idea how to deal with a second modification to the already modified element.(I'll update again soon. Unless, OP has an idea ;))

Comment: when i'm answering i'm getting the same issue when you only select "A" in text it will bold "A" everywhere in text.

Comment: Ah. I missed that. Give me a second

Comment: @YaseenAhmad fixed that one :) I'll try and fix the issue I mentioned after school.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Removed jQuery dependency**
You can achieve this using CSS.
First, you need to separate each word with a span.
Then add class strong on the span from where the event originated

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementsByClassName("parent-bodytext")[0].onclick = function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt && tgt.nodeName === 'SPAN') {
      tgt.classList.add('strong');
    }
  };
};
```

```css
.strong{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-bodytext">
     <p><span>Hello</span></p>
     <p><span>This</span> <span>one</span> <span>is</span></p>
     <p><span>Sample</span> <span>Text</span></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Nice answer but he want add strong only with select text not full text.

Comment: Is it possible without jquery ? Using basic api's of HTML something like element.innerHTML, document.getSelection(), getRangeAt(0).

Comment: @AvinashJadhav removed jQuery dependecy.

Comment: @YaseenAhmad changed code a bit, now class strong is only added to selected word, You can run code snippet and try.