# jQuery TextArea Bug?

Tags: jquery, textarea

I have a simple textarea with a button:

I change the content of the textarea with

```
$("button.test").click(function(){
   $("#config_oh").contentEditable = true;
$("#config_oh").html("Hello World);

});
```

This works. But if I type inside the textarea and re-run the script, it doesn't work: The content is there (I can see it with Chrome inspector) but no content is displayed on the webpage. Why?

If I update the the content of the `textarea` with `val()`, it works, but no HTML rendering is performed, e.g. I see html special chars.

Comment: Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea

Comment: I did it in the code: is that not right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I suggest to make a custome div with conteneditable=true, as suggested in the comments. In this way, .html() method works as usual.

```
<style>
        .editable {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 5px;
            resize: both;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        </style>
<button class="test">Click</button>
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true" id="config_oh"> MY TEXT HERE </div>

<script>
$("button.test").click(function(){   
   $("#config_oh").html("Hello World);
});
</script>
```

In this way, even after typing inside the "textarea" the button click works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

replace

`$("#config_oh").html("Hello World);`

with

`$("#config_oh").val("Hello World");`

Comment: I know, but 1) why this behaviour; 2) the val is not rendered....html special chars are being shown

Comment: Any value you put into the textarea, through manually typing or using a preset value (Like we are in the example), is going to be rendered in plaintext.

Comment: If you wanted to render html on the page, your best bet would be to add the contentEditable tag onto a div element. Something similar to [this](http://jsbin.com/oBiBoBE/10/edit?html,output) would do it.

Comment: It is not true: If I do .html("&#13";") this is rendered as html (the first time only)

Comment: That behavior is quite strange.

Comment: Unfortunately, your not going to be able to render actual div's or any actual html tags similar to that without using something similar to what i linked before.

Special html characters however, i'm unsure as to why it would render out first time round and refuse to do it thereafter

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the text in the input type box. you use val().
input type have a property **value**. 
eg:

```
$("#config_oh").val("Hello World");
```

this should be worked