# How to change the content of an Angular field textarea using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to change the color of a `textarea` in an Angular app using jQuery but it does not work.

What should I do? It says `$ is not defined`.
HTML:

```
<body>
     <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testController">
        <textarea id="abc">abc
          </textarea>

     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular js:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('testController', function($scope, $http) {    
      var tdVal =$("#abc");
      var x = tdVal.innerHTML;
      tdVal.html ("<span style='color: rgba(220, 0, 0, 1)'>" + x"</span>");
});
```

Comment: DOM manipulation should be done within a directive, no need for jquery. I can add snippet if you'd like. LMO

Answer (score 1):

You are not just changing color, but the control itself. If changing color is the intent:

```
var elem = angular.element('#abc');
elem.css('color', 'rgba(220, 0, 0, 1)');
```

for value update, angular provides you **bind** directive.

```
$scope.value = 'some value'
```

and in view

```
<textarea id="#abc" ng-bind="value"></textarea>
```

Comment: Does not work for me. i get this error"Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/jqLite/nosel.And another thing what if i want to change the value of some to "red" and value to "blue.How can i achieve that.Can you elaborate more on the code . I am very new to angular

Comment: looks like there is any external dependency missing in your angular app. angular.module('app_name', [pass_dependencies_here]);

Comment: if you want to update multiple controls then i suggest you to look at angular directives.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it does work if there are not some other dependincies:

```
$('#abc').css('color', 'rgba(220, 0, 0, 1)');
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you want to render HTML within `textarea` tag, which is not allowed by browsers, but what you can do is to use editable `div` element:

```
<div id="abc" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

check out [Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea#answer-4705882)

`angular.element` by default uses *jQueryLight* which is limited version og jQuery. You should use `ng-style` angular directive:

```
<div id="abc" contenteditable="true">
  <span ng-style="{color: 'rgba(220, 0, 0, 1)'}">abc</span>
</div>
```

or you can assign to `ng-style` your custom function which will return CSS object, according to your logic.