# Select a span in a TinyMCE textarea with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce-4

I'm using tinymce in my app with jquery. I am also using the jquery add in for tinymce to load it all locally.

I am pretty noob with jquery but I think I should be able to get it like this.

```
<h1 class="class">John</h1>
<form>
    <textarea id="id">
        <p>Hello <span class="class">John</span>,</p>
    </textarea>
</form>

<script>
    // Doesn't work for either
    $('form#id.class').text('Mark');

    // Doesn't Work Either for the textarea but does the h1
    $('.class').text('Mark');
</script>
```

But of course it's not working or why would I be posting this. What am I doing wrong?

I am importing jquery and can grab other things just like that and it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea

Comment: Instead of `$('form#id.class')`, the selector should be `$('form #id .class')` (notice the spaces after form and #id - they indicate the next part of the selector is a descendant). Of course, if #id is unique (as it should be), all you need is `$('#id .class')`

Comment: This is right with just jquery I think the problem is with tinymce. It's being a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load TinyMCE to replace a `<textarea>` the typing you do is not automatically synced with the original `<textarea>`.  Once TinyMCE is loaded you are working in an iFrame - not the original `<textarea>`.  When you submit the form using a standard form submit TinyMCE automatically updates the underling `<textarea>` before the form is submitted.  If you want to get the current value from the editor you can do one of two things:

- Use the `get()` API to talk directly to TinyMCE
- Use the `triggerSave()` API to manually update the underlying `<textarea>` before you try to work with the `<textarea>`

The `get()` API allows you to target a specific instance of the editor on the page and then use the `getContent()` API to get the data.

- https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#get
- https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent

The `triggerSave()` API tells TinyMCE to update the underlying `<textarea>` immediately after which you can interact with the data in the `<textarea>` to get what you need.

- https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#triggersave

Comment: Would you be willing to give me an example of how I should do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the jQuery library?

If not you're going to either want to download jQuery [here](http://jquery.com/download/) or use the CDN which can be found [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/).

If that's not your problem then take a look at the API Documentation for jQuery to see if you're using .text() correctly.

Here is the link: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Also, you shouldn't be using html tags in a textarea. Textareas render everything inside them as text. You'll want to use a content editable div which looks like this `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`

Comment: This is in a form, so I need the section to be an input. How can I make that work?

Answer (score 0):

The content of `<textarea>` is a text string.

So you'll need to manipulate it the same way that you might manipulate any other text string.

**Working Example:**

```js
var textArea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
var textAreaContent = textArea.textContent;
textAreaContent = textAreaContent.replace('<span class="class">John</span>','<span class="class">Mark</span>');
textArea.textContent = textAreaContent;
```

```html
<form>
    <textarea id="id">
        <p>Hello <span class="class">John</span>,</p>
    </textarea>
</form>
```

**N.B.** the jQuery for the native javascript above is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('textarea').text($('textarea').text().replace('<span class="class">John</span>','<span class="class">Mark</span>'));

});
```