# How to insert text inside textarea and convert p in <br> without to see the html in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following which is fine, it does convert the `<p>` tags into `<br>` and wrap the whole text in a `<p>`. however I am seeing the html tags `<p>` and `<br>` inside the text area, how can I only see the line breaks without to see the html tags in it?

```
<textarea id ="usp-content"><textarea>

$(blurbt).find('p').each(function(){
   $( this ).replaceWith( $( this ).text() + "<br/>" );
});
$(blurbt).wrapInner("<p></p>");
var pOnly  = $(blurbt).html();
$('#usp-content').text(pOnly);
```

I'd simply would like to paste the plain text while keeping the line breaks visually not with the `<br>`

Comment: Html code would be helpful.

Comment: @Kinduser hi, I believe i got it, we cannot render html inside the textarea, i should be using contenteditable="true" :( yet I really need a text area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a contenteditable="true".

You can simple do the following:

Change `$('#usp-content').text(pOnly);` to:

```
$('#usp-content').val(pOnly.replace(/<br[\s\/]*>/gm, "\n"));
```

To reverse this incase you are sending the content of the textarea to server side and want html markup, simply use:

```
var data = $('#usp-content').val().replace(/\\n/gm, "<br>");
```

Comment: what happens then if I am sending the textarea with php? How will it consider the /n?

Comment: thanks a lot, one last thing, by changing that line it only replace one <br>, should we have it in a .each() ?

Comment: Updated the answer to allow multiple and multiline replace

Comment: Just added a g character along with the m. This is to allow for both multiline and multiple occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot render the html inside a `textarea` we need to use a `contenteditable` in a `div`, see [SO Answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea). Therefore in my case I will have to place a `div` with html formatted and set the `textarea` as hidden to get the same value as per what user sees.

```
 <div contenteditable="true"></div>
```