# Why textarea doesnt support iframe embed?

Tags: html

I have a textarea input, When I put iframe inside it i get the same thing

example:
I put this code

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-0uBK0T298k" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I get the same thing in my page

[image]

Any solution?

Comment: To be clear, you want the iframe to render inside your textarea?

Comment: @milo526 i want to put a video embed from youtube inside my textarea and get the video (i have admin panel)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot render HTML inside a `textarea` tag. You could use a content editable div.

See this answer for more information on the subject: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705882/5514456

Comment: i want to put a video embed from youtube inside my textarea and get the video (i have admin panel)