# How to display content of a php and html file into a textarea?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display the content of a file that contains both php code and html code into a textarea. I did

```
<textarea name='codemodifier' cols='110' rows='35' id='codemodifier' class='form-control' style='height: 75vh;'><?php echo file_get_contents("myfile.php"); ?></textarea>
```

However instead of it displaying only the content of the file, it displays other html codes under the textarea

[image]

I edited my code and did

```
<textarea name='codemodifier' cols='110' rows='35' id='codemodifier'
class='form-control' style='height: 75vh;'><?php echo
htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("myfile.php")); ?></textarea>
```

And then nothing shows anymore in the textarea. I get the same problem when i use htmlentites instead of htmlspecialchars.

**How to display content of a php and html file  into a textarea ?**

Comment: "I edited my code and did" - the quote is empty, you're missing something.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` should do the trick.

Comment: I can't understand the language in the error but it seems to be something related to session

Comment: Check the page source and see what it looks like. I'm not 100% sure about what your actual issue is though. Is the text below the textarea suppose to be inside it?

Comment: I think this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848). Does it help?

Comment: I guess the OP gave up...

Comment: @neuhaus `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities` did not work. When i apply it to it nothing is displayed anymore

@mrid What could it possibly be because i am well logged in ?

@bezet No not really. I need to edit the content in a textarea because i am creating a one file and dont want to use jquery or any library to achieve my goal

@MagnusEriksson Please do you have a solution to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Those look like UTF-8 characters, try decoding them using [`utf_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) before you output the contents of the file in to the textarea.

> This function converts the string data from the UTF-8 encoding to ISO-8859-1. Bytes in the string which are not valid UTF-8, and UTF-8 characters which do not exist in ISO-8859-1 (that is, characters above U+00FF) are replaced with ?.

Comment: That did not work . I added tge utf_decode and even set the charset to ISO-8859-1 but the text is still coming out of the textarea

Comment: Did you try `<?php echo
htmlspecialchars(utf_decode(file_get_contents("myfile.php"))); ?>`

Comment: Could you please give us the contents of the file?