# How should you encode a textarea's contents

Tags: html, asp.net, encoding, textarea

If I have a text area that can display user entered input. How should I encode it to prevent any security issues?

For instance suppose I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <textarea></textarea><script>alert('Hello');</script></textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How should I encode the contents of the textarea so that it shows the `</textarea><script>` as text rather than running it?

I'm using ASP.Net, but I'm really after a general answer for HTML.

This is different to "[Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)" as I don't want to render HTML inside the textarea where as with that question they did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Comment: @kblok this is a different question. I DON'T want to render html inside the textarea.

Answer (score 2):

You use `HTMLEncode`.

```
<textarea><%= Server.HtmlEncode("</textarea><script>alert('Hello');</script>") %></textarea>
```

Or

```
TextBox1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(myString);
```

Comment: This is what I thought, but was a bit concerned this might encode things that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post <script>the tag will be picked up.
Displaying a tag as text type **&lt;** and **&gt;** they will be displayed as < > [Link](https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

So the html would look like:

```
<textarea> &lt;/textarea&gt; &lt;script&gt;alert('Hello');&lt;/script&gt; </textarea>
```

but @VDWWD answer is a better solution for asp.net development.