# How to pre-fill a text area from a string that contains <br /> tags in between the string

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am getting a string like `1 2 <br /> 3 <br /> 4 4` and i want to render this in a textarea with `LINE BREAKS`.

Please have a look at the jsfiddle for what I am trying to acheive- 
https://jsfiddle.net/pejxqn68/1/

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <textarea value={this.props.textareaValue}></textarea>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello textareaValue="1 2 <br /> 3 <br /> 4 4" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

## How can i render the string in the textarea such that the `br` tags are rendered as a line break?

Edit -

Since I cannot change the `textarea` to a `div` it is not possible in my case.

Also, I would like a more `react` way of solving it (if any)

Comment: You can render HTML into a `textarea`, here's a post about content editable divs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Comment: Is there a reactjs solution?

Comment: Why do you think it's not possible? I think Jayce's comment has confused you. This solution works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/pahund/pejxqn68/24/

Comment: @PatrickHund thanks!

It has solved my usecase :)

Comment: My bad, I meant can't*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about react, but I know that to make line returns, you need to transform `<br />` to `\n`.

So do something along the lines of

```
"1 2 <br /> 3 <br /> 4 4".replace(/\<br +\/\>/g, '\n')
```

As shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kxo2s06/1/)

Answer (score 4):

this might help; replace all `br` with `\n`
    class Hello extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
            
              
            
        );
      }
    }

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello textareaValue={"1 2 <br /> 3 <br /> 4 4".replace(/<br\s?\/?>/g,"\n")} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

working snippet https://jsfiddle.net/pejxqn68/22/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to replace the *<br>* tag with a line break character, like this:

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <textarea value={this.props.textareaValue.replace(/<br \/>/g, '\n')} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello textareaValue="1 2 <br /> 3 <br /> 4 4" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pahund/pejxqn68/24/