# HTML tag not works inside <textarea>?

Tags: php, html, textarea

Here is my code:

```
   <textarea  rows='15'  cols='90'  name="activities">  
        <?php
        echo "<p style='color: green;'>text area is here</p>";
        ?> 
    </textarea>
```

The output is `<p style='color: green;'>text area is here</p>`;
But I want the output to be  `text area is here` in green. Please provide some hint?

Comment: That's not how text areas work. You need to put the styling on the `<textarea>` element itself.

Comment: don't use html tag inside textarea tag

Comment: As mentioned before; you shouldn't render HTML in a text area. You should only display plain text.

Comment: If you **_really_** need to do this you could use some derivative of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49827767/7841614) but this means that you will be manually rendering the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect.

You can either use inline style to make your font color green like,

```
<textarea style="color:green;"  rows="15"  cols="90"  name="activities">  
text area is here
</textarea>
```

or

define it inside a style tag in your main html page in head section like,

```
<style>
textarea{
color: green;
}
</style>
```

Alternatively you can style the textarea input in your external style sheet like,

```
textarea{
color: green;
}
```

You can also assign an id or a class to textarea input and then add css style.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use css to make the text inside your `<textarea>` green?

```
textarea {
    color: green;
}
```

And remove the `<p>` tag in your `<textarea>` so you only have:

```
<textarea  rows='15'  cols='90'  name="activities">
    text area is here
</textarea>
```

```css
textarea {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<textarea  rows='15'  cols='90'  name="activities">
    text area is here
</textarea>
```