# How to add highlight background to the matched array item in textarea

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, match

I'm trying to highlight a matched name from user search. If the user search is in the array, the matched array item should be highlighted in the text area. How to accomplish this?
 Here is what I have so far.

```js
function search() {
  var list = $('#textArea').val();
  var listArr = list.split(',');
  $('#textArea').html(listArr);
  var userSearch = $('#nameSearch').val();

  var i = 0;
  while (listArr[i]) {
    var res = listArr[i].indexOf(userSearch);
    if (res !== -1) {
      console.log(userSearch + ' is on the list.');
      //highlight matched name in textArea
    }
    i++;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <textarea class="nameList" name="names" id="textArea" cols="30" rows="10">joe, monica, harry, hanna</textarea>
</div>
<input type="text" id="nameSearch" />
<button onclick="search()">Search By Name</button>
```

Here is a link to the codepen:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/gatehrdy/pen/JaXKor)

Comment: Try to check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea

Answer (score 0):

To match the fist occurrence you need to focus the `textarea` first and then use [setSelectionRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange).

Also since `setSelectionRange` is not jQuery method you would need to access the html element via the 0 index e.g. `$txt[0].setSelectionRange`

Try something like this:

```js
function search() {
  var $txt = $('#textArea')
  $txt.focus()
  var list = $txt.val();
  var search = $('#nameSearch').val();
  var index = list.indexOf(search);
  $txt[0].setSelectionRange(index, index + search.length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <textarea class="nameList" name="names" id="textArea" cols="30" rows="10">joe, monica, harry, hanna</textarea>
</div>
<input type="text" id="nameSearch" />
<button onclick="search()">Search By Name</button>
```

Comment: It just will highlight the first match text, not for all, right :))

Comment: Did he ask to highlight all? I must have missed that