# how to display html string(html tags) as content in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to display the html tags in a div tag so i used like,

```
<p [innerHTML]="data"> // data is a html tags for ex: h1 tag
</p>
```

it is working fine but if i want to print in the text area,
it is not translating the html code and directly printing the html code
like,

```
<textarea  rows="4" cols="50">
    {{data}}
</textarea>
```

Here is the working [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq44c3?file=src/app/app.component.html) on stackblitz,

Comment: <textarea> is not capable to handle html tags, it interprets the value as plain text.

You can use html editors in this case.

Comment: I've got it what you want to, but the textarea is not allowing to render any HTML tags as @TejPatil said. You can use `contenteditable="true"` (only as idea).

Comment: Please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG .I hope this helps you. (for example, https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/demo/#inline)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, what you are looking for is a content editable div. Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/8zevmL4d/), but basically you need to (just translate this to Angular):

```
<div contenteditable="true">This is the first line.<br>
    See, how the text fits here, also if<br>there is a <strong>linebreak</strong> at the e nd?
    <br>It works nicely.
    <br>
    <br><span style="color: lightgreen">Great</span>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question already has answer in stackblitz,
[Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

What you are doing is, set the div tag editable