# How to display HTML in textarea?

Tags: html, textarea, razor-pages, tag-helpers, .net-core-2.2

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2, razor pages. I have a database field called EmailSignatureHTML that stores the HTML version of the user's email signature.

I have textarea in which I want to display that signature like this:

> Thanks,
>
> Tyrion Lannister
> *Hand of the King*

Using the razor tag helper this is what I have...

```
<textarea asp-for="@Model.EmailSettings.EmailSignatureHTML" class="form-control mb-2" cols="30" rows="10" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

Problem is that it displays the signature in the text area with the HTML markup like this:

```
<div><b>Thanks,</b></div><div><b><br></b></div><div><b>Tyrion Lannister<br><i>Hand of the King</i></b></div><div><b><br></b></div><div><br></div>
```

Not sure how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Comment: thank you. I'll check it out.