# how do wrap HTML content into textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I have done some bit of script of trying to wrap div elements with textarea. This will enable be log the values and submit them to the database.
So far when I try to wrap up everything with texarea its displays HTML tags instead of display readable elements.

with only divs, its display readable elements

```
 <div  class="editable w-50" contenteditable="true" id="fields">
        <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <label contenteditable="false" class="bg-info rounded shadow-lg text-white w-50 text-center font-weight-bolder ">Keyword</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li >Ex. air conditioning</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                 <div class="col">
                    <label contenteditable="false" class="bg-info rounded shadow-lg text-white w-50 text-center font-weight-bolder ">Density</label>

                    <ul>
                        <li>i.e Density</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Tried to do this with textarea

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="conent" >
    <div  class="editable w-50" contenteditable="true" id="fields" >
        <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <label contenteditable="false" class="bg-info rounded shadow-lg text-white w-50 text-center font-weight-bolder ">Keyword</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li >Ex. air conditioning</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                 <div class="col">
                    <label contenteditable="false" class="bg-info rounded shadow-lg text-white w-50 text-center font-weight-bolder ">Density</label>

                    <ul>
                        <li>i.e Density</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </textarea>
```

Its fails and only display HTML tags.

Kindly help to solve the problem

Comment: did you want it? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea

Comment: textarea can only contain text, not html.

Comment: @Ouroborus yes,

Comment: @mankowitz I am satisfied with your answer