# How to display plain text instead of with HTMLText in textarea in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How to display plain text instead of with HTMLText in textarea in ASP.Net Core

this is my view

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <label asp-for="Decription" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Description</label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <textarea type="text" asp-for="Decription" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is my View

[image]

How to display plain text in this **textarea** instead of HtmlText.

Comment: Hi @Abhay,Your code is working as it should, but `<textarea>` elements cannot contain formatted HTML. 

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea), "character data" is the only permitted content for a `<textarea>`.

If you need something like a textarea that allows for formatted HTML, you are looking for a WYSIWYG editor, like CKEditor, TinyMCE, or Kendo's Editor.

Comment: @Html.Raw("your html text")

Comment: check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Comment: I have already use CKEditor but this Is use only for admin and this is client-side and my client-side requirement is not to show editor just show textarea and those data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show your content without any formatting, you could use `Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty)` to strip all of Html tags from your string.

You could change in backend:

```
var model = new TestModel() { 
       Decription="<p><strong>Test</strong> is a Special Item in our <i>Restraunt</i>.</p>" 
};
model.Decription = Regex.Replace(model.Decription, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
```

Or change in frontend:

```
@model TestModel

@using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

<textarea type="text" name="Decription" class="form-control">@Regex.Replace(Model.Decription, "<.*?>", String.Empty)</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me,

If we change only in view then it also works. no need to use in backend controller side  **Regex.Replace(model.Decription, "<.*?>", String.Empty);** If we use only frontend side then also work.