# How to integrate the HTML string into classic editor to show it in formatted string?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, ckeditor, text-editor, ckeditor5

How to convert the html string into formatted string using classic text editor here I used the Html.Raw() method but it is not working:

[image: How to convert the html string into formatted string using classic text editor here I used the Html.Raw() method but it is not working.]

```html
<textarea id="@areaId"  class="areacls" data-href="@item.Id" onclick="createEditor(@areaId)"  name="hoverC" style="background-color: rgb(221, 226, 237); width: 100%; overflow: hidden; border: none; box-shadow: none; text-overflow: ellipsis; " rows="3">@item.Description</textarea>

<script>
const editors = new Map();

 function createEditor( elementToReplace ) {
          //debugger;
        return ClassicEditor
        .create( elementToReplace )
        .then( editor => {
            editors.set( elementToReplace, editor );
                   
        })
        .catch( err => console.error( err.stack ) );
      }
</script>
```

The string in the image card is coming from the database with Html elements. I want to convert it into applied HTML string.Like in the given snip:
[image: The string in the image card is coming from the database with Html elements. I want to convert it into applied HTML string.Like in the given snip]

Comment: I have updated my answer, pls check it whether help you.

Comment: @JasonPan  Regex.Replace converts the html string into plain string. and I want it in formatted text like the html element i have applied on it. even the letters are bold, italic etc. I want when i click on the editor then the tools will be enable.Before that only text will see in the editor area.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Comment: @JasonPan Yaa It helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE

I found the reason, we can't render string with html tags inside the textarea. And I found the good solution for you, we can use

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

[image]

For more details. please check this link:

### [Rendering HTML inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705882/7687666)

[image]

```
@using System.Net;
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "75599709 Page";
    string description = @"<i><strong>Virtual</strong></i>World ABC friend<strong>hii hello</strong>abc jitesh education<strong>hello all</strong>";
}
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/29.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea id="editor1" class="areacls" data-href="item1" onclick="createEditor('editor1')" name="hoverC" style="background-color: rgb(221, 226, 237); width: 100%; overflow: hidden; border: none; box-shadow: none; text-overflow: ellipsis; " rows="3">@Regex.Replace(description, "<.*?>", String.Empty)</textarea>

@section Scripts {
    @{

        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
        <script>
            const editors = new Map();

            function createEditor(elementToReplace) {
                //debugger;
                return ClassicEditor
                    .create(document.querySelector('#' + elementToReplace))
                    .then(editor => {
                        editors.set(elementToReplace, editor);

                    })
                    .catch(err => console.error(err.stack));
            }

        </script>

    }
    }
```

---

Change your function `createEditor` like below:

```
        function createEditor(elementToReplace) {
            //debugger;
            return ClassicEditor
                .create(document.querySelector('#' + elementToReplace))
                .then(editor => {
                    editors.set(elementToReplace, editor);

                })
                .catch(err => console.error(err.stack));
        }
```

Then the issue will be fixed.

---

**Optional**

I don't think this issue related to Html.Raw, you can find my code works well. If you still think related to Html.Raw. You can try below code in your .cshtml

```
@Html.Raw(@WebUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.result))
```

---

#### Test Code And Result

*1. Test Page source code*

```
@using System.Net;
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "75599709 Page";
    string description = @"<i><strong>Virtual</strong></i>World ABC friend<strong>hii hello</strong>abc jitesh education<strong>hello all</strong>";
}
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/29.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea id="editor1" class="areacls" data-href="item1" onclick="createEditor('editor1')" name="hoverC" style="background-color: rgb(221, 226, 237); width: 100%; overflow: hidden; border: none; box-shadow: none; text-overflow: ellipsis; " rows="3">@description</textarea>

@section Scripts {
    @{

        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
        <script>
            const editors = new Map();

            function createEditor(elementToReplace) {
                //debugger;
                return ClassicEditor
                    .create(document.querySelector('#' + elementToReplace))
                    .then(editor => {
                        editors.set(elementToReplace, editor);

                    })
                    .catch(err => console.error(err.stack));
            }

            
        </script>

    }
    }
```

*2. Test Result*

[image]

Comment: The text with Html elements you see initially after run the code i.e <i><strong>Virtual</strong></i> World ABC friend <strong>hii hello </strong>abc jitesh education<strong> hello all</strong>. I want to remove that html tags from here before editor enable. My code also works upto this. thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @RumanAli Can you tell me what you need? What else can I do for you?

Comment: Hi @RumanAli, I am using `@Regex.Replace(description, "<.*?>", String.Empty)` and it works fine.

Comment: Hi @RumanAli, I figure out the reason why it not works, and I have update my answer with the best solution.