# how to add tag span into specific word in textarea by click this word if clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When I want to add a tag to a word in the text area, the tag is not accepted. Is there any way to add a tag to the text in the text area by clicking on the word I want to add a tag to?
such as span tags

```html
<label>
  <textarea class="string-example" name="textarea3" id="textarea3" cols="122" rows="17">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</textarea>
</label>
```

Comment: There's not much we can do with your `<?php echo $str2; ?>`, when asking questions, try to minimize unknowns by either pasting the resulting rendered markup (inspect element, you know the drill...) - For this example one can suppose there's just text.  Edited your question to reflect.

Comment: Would `<div contenteditable>Lorem <mark>ipsum</mark> dolor sit amet...</div>`  be a viable solution for your case?

Comment: By adding a tag, do you mean wrapping whichever word you click with the tag markup? For example, if the text area says (in plaintext) "Hello, world", and you click the second word, the textarea should then say "Hello, <span>world</span>"? If so, are you only interested in adding span tags?

Comment: Now, you can’t.
The question is answered here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is you double-click a text in the textarea, the text will be highlighted. If you just want to style it, use CSS: `::selection`

```css
textarea::selection {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit ipsum. Eaque, facere architecto. Ipsum quas, modi impedit veritatis earum sunt quo reiciendis. Hic, sapiente earum fuga accusamus qui eos itaque provident! Eaque, ipsum in.</textarea>
```

Either use `<div contenteditable>` instead of textarea,
or
use the Textarea as a DIV overlay - which will have the highlighted markup instead

```css
.markable {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.markable>* {
  all: unset;
  outline: 1px solid #999;
  vertical-align: top;
  font: 16px/1.4 monospace;
}

.markable div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: transparent;
}

.markable textarea {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="markable">
  <div>Lorem <mark>ipsum</mark> dolor sit amet...</div>
  <textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</textarea>
</div>
```

The above is a proof of concept, you'll still need JavaScript in order to clone the text into the `.highliter` DIV, insert the `<mark>` element child around a desired text `selection` - and also make sure (if needed) that the underlying DIV scrolls in sync with the textarea.

```js
const search = "ipsum";

const regEsc = (str) => str.replace(/[/\-\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');

const markable = (elMarkable) => {
  const elDiv = elMarkable.querySelector("div");
  const elTxt = elMarkable.querySelector("textarea");
  const updateScroll = () => {
    elDiv.scrollTop = elTxt.scrollTop;
  };
  const updateMark = () => {
    const val = elTxt.value;
    const markedVal = val.replace(new RegExp(`\\b${regEsc(search)}\\b`, "gi"), `<mark>$&</mark>`);
    elDiv.setHTML(markedVal);
  };
  elTxt.addEventListener("scroll", updateScroll);
  elTxt.addEventListener("input", updateScroll);
  elTxt.addEventListener("input", updateMark);
  
  // Init:
  updateScroll();
  updateMark();
};

document.querySelectorAll(".markable").forEach(markable);
```

```css
.markable {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.markable>* {
  all: unset;
  outline: 1px solid #999;
  vertical-align: top;
  font: 16px/1.4 monospace;
}

.markable div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  overflow: auto;
}

.markable textarea {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<p>Edit the text in textarea below. The string to be highlighted is "ipsum" (case insensitive)</p>
<div class="markable">
  <div></div>
  <textarea  name="textarea3" cols="40" rows="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit ipsum. Eaque, facere architecto. Ipsum quas, modi impedit veritatis earum sunt quo reiciendis. Hic, sapiente earum fuga accusamus qui eos itaque provident! Eaque, ipsum in.</textarea>
</div>
```

I'll leave the slngle click selection to the reader.

Comment: Is it possible to make it yellow when you click on it, otherwise it is normal?

Comment: @KurdiBashur which example (from the ones above) are you referring to?