# Php Textarea Can't Include textarea value, please help me :)

Tags: php

please help, some days I searched and did not find ?

i have " test.php "

```
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" Name="">
<textarea name=""></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="help me">
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

and "index.php "

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$test = "test.php";
?>
<textarea name=""><?php readfile($test ); ?></textare>
</body>
</html>
```

my problem,
why the submit button is outside the textarea ?
and not read it as a string or value?

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't really think that this can be done with textareas

Comment: You can use get_all_contents in php it can work surely.and when u get the values from txt file and assign in variable and give that variable name in  textarea value it will work

Answer (score 0):

[`<textarea>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) can contain only text. Controls cannot be embedded inside it. You should use [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) tag to be able to nest another html in your page.

Comment: Mr. bhovhannes
Thanks
I've been using an iframe
I mean using a textarea as rich editor

Comment: maybe I can use this script:

Html
<textarea class="editable"></textarea >

js
$('.editable').each(function(){
    this.contentEditable = true;
});

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate with [Tags inside textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926723/tags-inside-textarea)

You can use "content editable div". An example using jquery was provided in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/XNkDx/)

Textareas cannot contain other tags. Your button is outside of the textarea because `<textarea name=""></textarea>` inside your `test.php` file actually is closing your main textarea and the rest of the code is taken as code in the main page and not as a content of the main textarea.