# Javascript how to pass variable and set color

Tags: javascript, html

I have two textarea

```
<textarea id="area1">Hello how are you</textarea>
<textarea id="area2"></textarea>
```

I want pass area1 value to area2 and show, then set  "Hello" to color red, "how are you" to color green

```
var area1=document.getElementById("area1");
var area2=document.getElementById("area2");
```

How to do this in JavaScript? thank you

Comment: you can't do that using `textarea`, instead you can use `contenteditable` div and wrap text using `span` and set style to it

Comment: on button click or what?

Comment: @managed resource onkeyup()

Comment: @Nick : he need seperate color for text

Answer (score 1):

To transfer the text you could use the `innerHTML` property of your `textarea` :

```
area2.innerHTML = area1.innerHTML;
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NeekGerd/rmo49cee/) for this.

But for the red color part, it will be way more difficult.

You won't be able to use 2 `textarea` for this. You'll have to create another container and style it as a `textarea`.

Here is a quick [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/NeekGerd/rmo49cee/3/) with the second element being a `div` instead of a `textarea`.

I didn't style the second element though.

```
var area1=document.getElementById("area1");
var area2=document.getElementById("area2");
var regex = /Hello/g;

area2.innerHTML = area1.innerHTML.split(regex)
                    .join('<span style="color:red;">Hello</span><span style="color:green;">')
                    + '</span>';
```

EDIT : Forgot the green part.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways to do this:

1. Using Basic code

HTML:

```
<div id="boom1">Some random text1</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
let element1 = document.getElementById("boom1")
element1.style.color = "red";
element1.style.fontWeight = "bold";
element1.style.fontSize = "2em";
```

---

2. Using .cssText

HTML:

```
<div id="boom2">Some random text2</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
let element2 = document.getElementById("boom2").style.cssText =  "color: blue; font-weight: bold; font-size: 2em"
```

---

3. Using Object.assign()

HTML:

```
<div id="boom3">Some random text3</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
let object1 = document.getElementById("boom3")
let styles = {color: "green", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "2em"}
let element3 = Object.assign(object1.style, styles)
```

or simply (without breaking down into variables):

```
let element3 = Object.assign(document.getElementById("boom3").style, {color: "green", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "2em"})
```

---

4. Using jQuery

HTML:

```
<div id="boom4">Some random text4</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#boom4").css({color: "orange", fontSize: "2em", fontWeight: "bold"})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to do that. Check out the code below.

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    // get button
    var button = document.getElementById('button');

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        // listen for clicks.
        // If button is clicked, execute doTheMagic()
        button.addEventListener('click', doTheMagic, false);
    }

    function doTheMagic() {
        // get both text areas
        var area1 = document.getElementById('area1');
        var area2 = document.getElementById('area2');

        // change colors
        area1.style.color = 'red';
        area2.style.color = 'green';

        // copy and paste value
        area2.value = area1.value;
    }
})();
```

Also, check out the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lbronsdijk/tfdvtc7v/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Getting the [text value from area1 is easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19790446/444255):

```
v = document.getElementById("area1").value
```

and so is setting it...

```
document.getElementById("bla").value = v;
```

But coloring is out of question: you *would* need a wrapping `<span>` or other tag, to apply different styles. However [tags are not allowed within textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/926762/444255).

What you probably want is a (way) more sophisticated javascript-Based Text editor, that supports colors (or bold, or other more sophisticated formatting beyond plain text) within a visual 'text area' of sorts....

You might also check out ...

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```