# can I add <span> inside <textarea> and make it useful?

Tags: css, html, tags

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        span {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

        <textarea readonly cols=200 rows=40>
            <span>
                hahahahaha
            </span>
        </textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

in this example，is there anyway I can make the text in `<span>` to be red in color
or can it be done by some other html tag like `<textarea>`?

Comment: Are you trying to implement a textarea placeholder or something?

Comment: If it is read only, why do you need it as a textarea?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926723/tags-inside-textarea. They basically give you the same option of using a contenteditable div.

Comment: It's called a **text**area, not an **html**area.

Comment: It's possible to separate styling of text by using a contenteditable element.
Here is fiddle of coloring particular chars on the fly: http://www.codeply.com/go/YHx9yphpHW

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format text in a <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't put an HTML element inside of a form field tag like `textarea` or `input`. You can, however, make the color in a textarea red using normal CSS.

```css
textarea {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<textarea>text</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternative method you can also use is to adjust the styles of the placeholder attribute.

link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/2yyydq5t/)

Hope this helps.

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

```html
Who are you?<br />
<textarea readonly rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Describe yourself here..."></textarea><br />
<input type="text" placeholder="red" />
```

Answer (score -2):

OK, now I konw I can't insert  into

and i have got another way

```
<style type="text/css"> 
        .testDiv{ 
            bottom: 36px;
            height: calc(100vh - 280px);
            resize: none;
            overFlow-x:scroll; 
            overFlow-y:scroll; 
        } 
        .keyword{
            color:red;
        }
</style> 

<div class='testDiv' id="keyword">
            one<br>
            two<br>
            three<br>
            <span class="keyword">four</span><br>
</div>
```

just add scroll,height css in div