# Javascript: How to detect certain characters within a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Edit to add: I first asked about a textarea - I had a feeling it just wasn't possible with a textarea by its nature. Could I do this with a contenteditable div?

Within a contenteditable div, when the user enters %TEST% I would like to add a span with a class around %TEST% to be able to add styling to it.

It runs if %TEST% is in the html, but I need it to run if %TEST% is typed in by the user.

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="myEntry">We're happy you're here, %TEST%. Let's get started.</div>
```

using jquery I have:

```
$('.myEntry).each(function () {
    var original = $(this).text();
    var new_version = original.split('%TEST%').join('<span class="stylizeMe">Test</span>');
    $(this).html(new_version)
});
```

Comment: you can't have `<span>` (or any element) inside a `<textarea>`

Comment: The "Permitted content" of a `<textarea>` is only Text - no other elements allowed

Comment: that's what I was afraid of :/

Comment: may be this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574522/contenteditable-put-caret-outside-inserted-span

Comment: Do you use this textarea to post some data ?

Comment: Yes, within a form.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want by content editable div, but do give this a look and maybe it might be of use for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956567/how-do-i-make-an-editable-div-look-like-a-text-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content model for `textarea` is [processed character data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926723/tags-inside-textarea) therefore element inside `textarea` will not accepted. However you can use [content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) div as alternative solution.

```
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Then you can use `jQuery` to update `%TEXT%` -> `<span class='myTest'>%TEST%</span>`, if you want to use `Javascript` you need to use `input` event beacuse `onchange` does not support for `contenteditable`

```
$('body').on('blur', '[contenteditable]', function() {
   $(this).html(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace(/%TEST%/g, "<span class='myTest'>%TEST%</span>"); 
  });
});
```

However `contenteditable` does not work as a form element therefore you have to use [Javascript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355583/can-div-with-contenteditable-true-be-passed-through-form/7355609) to apply `contenteditable` in your work.

```
<script>
        document.getElementById("textarea").value = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
</script>

<div id="content" contenteditable="true">Text</div>

<form>
    <textarea id="textarea" style="display:none"></textarea>
</form>
```

Workable sample: https://jsbin.com/zuyemabiwo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Yes this is so close! But, if %TEST% is entered by the user more than once, it only applies the span to the most recent entry

Answer (score 2):

this can't be done with **textarea** Element

try to simulate textarea element with another element like *div* or *span* or *pre*